# Drupal - Views Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I am working with views slideshow on Drupal to display a image per page on a designated block. The issue I am experiencing is that the module is cycling through different images. I want to somehow change it either through views or jquery.cycle.all.js to simply display a static image per page and not be cycling through different ones.

Can you please help me

Link to jquery: http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle.all.js

Comment: Why are you using slideshow to display a single image?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to show on the node page it was uploaded to, in your view add a "contextual filter" for "Content: Nid".  Under "When the filter value is NOT available" choose "Provide default value" then "Content ID from URL". Also, if you only want one image to show you don't need to use a views slideshow. Instead change you view "Format" to "Unformatted list".

Comment: How would I configure it so only one image appears per page. So for instance on the home page I would have one image, then on the about us page there would be a different image and they wouldn't all appear on the same page?

Comment: Ok it sounds like you are going for something a little different than what I described. Are you wanting to display one random image on each page, so when you reload the page it changes? Or do you just want a very specific image on a certain page?

Comment: Yeah, I want a specific image to be displayed on a certain page, each page will have a different image that doesn't cycle through a slideshow. Each image will be distinctive from page to page and simply be static.

Comment: It sounds like you may just want to use a regular block, a separate one for each page, rather than using views. Or if all of your pages are node pages, you could use the views method I described in my answer.